# Evenly space non-Path elements in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Apologies if this has been asked already specifically, I couldn't find it if it has.

My question, is in Illustrator is there a way/option/trick to for example select multiple blocks of Text and make them evenly spaced Horizontally within the area of the artboard?

I know with a Path you can split it into a Grid, but what about something like Text elements? Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Distribute spacing buttons on the **Align Panel**.

[image]

You can't *split* area text boxes. But you can draw a series of rectangles and then convert them to area text boxes.

Comment: Ah that's a clever solution, I was hoping I could just have a bunch of Text blocks, select them all, and space them evenly. I'll have to go look at the differences between the TextBox and regular type. Apologize for the ignorance but I normally do more dev than design anymore and I was much better with PS than I am AI so far. Thanks though, I imagine I should go ahead and count this correct. Cheers! :)